# Read Bytes from End of File Backward Until Condition is Reached

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I have a number of large (> 2Gig) files that are all binary until the last so-many bytes, at which point they are regular text until the end of the file. Essentially its a small xml header followed by a giant binary payload, followed by a tiny xml footer. I need to find the position in the file of the binary-footer boundary, write the footer to a string, and truncate the original file PRECISELY after the last binary byte.

I started doing this in the following manner (I could not cut and paste directly due to sensitivity of work environment so please don't be too critical if not compiling for you):

```
String footerString = "";
String startOfEndString = "</endTag:lastTag"
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try(raf = new RandomAccessFile(tmpFile, "rw")) {
   raf.seek(raf.length() - 2);
   byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
   boolean readMore = true;


  while(readMore == true){
    raf.read(bytes, 0, 2);
    sb.insert(0, new String(bytes));
    footerString = sb.subString(0, new String(bytes));

   if (footerString.contains(startOfEndString)) {
      footerString = footerString.substring(footerString.indexOf(startOfEndString));
      readMore = false;
      }
  }

  FileChannel payloadChannel = raf.getChannel();
  payloadChannel.truncate(raf.length() - footerString.length());
```

This is not working. The footerString as it is built, does not have the characters in the correct order. Further, even if it were I am not confident the line "payloadChannel.truncate(raf.length() - footerString.length());" would truncate the file to precisely the correct byte position.

I suspect there is a better way to do this, but I do not know what it is. Grateful for any insights. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to assume the xml footer is always < n bytes where 'n' is a reasonably small number, e.g. 1000.  I understand the footer length could vary but can it be constrained in size for your problem?  And how are the text portions encoded - UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks Andy. There is no way to guarantee that the the footer starts within say 1000 bytes, but yes,  I can probably get away with doing in seeks in chunks (eg, 1000 bytes, then if not there, go back 2000 from the end, etc). I will try that later this morning. Thank you.